# How do I prove the following absolute value inequality?

Tags: inequality

Say $a \in [0, 0.5)$ and $b \in [0.5, 1]$ then:

$|\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}| \le \frac{4}{9} \big(|a - \frac{a}{4}| + |b - \frac{b}{5}| \big)$.

I've worked on this for sometime, starting with the left side, and tried various different ways of applying the triangle inequality. So far I've had no luck proving it and would appreciate if someone and help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangle's inequality implies
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}\right| &\le\left|\frac{a}{4}\right|+\left|\frac{b}{5}\right|\\
&\le\frac{|a|}{3}+\frac{15}{9}\frac{|b|}{5}\qquad\text{since }|x|\ge0\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\\
&\le\frac{4}{9}\left|\frac{3a}{4}\right|+\frac{4}{9}\left|\frac{4b}{5}\right|\\
&= \frac{4}{9} \left(\left|a - \frac{a}{4}\right| + \left|b - \frac{b}{5}\right| \right)
\end{align*}
Inequality holds for every pair of real numbers ($a$, $b$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe that since $a\geq 0$, $a-\frac{a}{4}=\frac{3}{4}a\geq 0$.  Similarly, $b-\frac{b}{5}\geq 0$, so we can drop the absolute values on the RHS.  Therefore, it is enough to prove:
$$
\left|\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}\right|\leq\frac{4}{9}\left(\frac{3}{4}a+\frac{4}{5}b\right).
$$

Now, we can deal with absolute value on the LHS:

- If $\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}\geq 0$, then we can drop the absolute value.  Then, it is enough to prove that 
  $$
  \frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}\leq\frac{4}{9}\left(\frac{3}{4}a+\frac{4}{5}b\right)=\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{16}{45}b.
  $$
  This is equivalent to proving that
  $$
  -\frac{1}{12}a\leq\frac{5}{9}b
  $$
  Since $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, this inequality is certainly true.
- If $\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}< 0$, then we can drop the absolute value by introducing a factor of $-1$.  Then, it is enough to prove that 
  $$
  \frac{b}{5}-\frac{a}{4}\leq\frac{4}{9}\left(\frac{3}{4}a+\frac{4}{5}b\right)=\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{16}{45}b.
  $$
  This is equivalent to proving that
  $$
  -\frac{7}{12}a\leq\frac{7}{9}b
  $$
  Since $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, this inequality is certainly true.

Now, this is only a hint because, in practice, one should start with the two cases $\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{5}\geq/<0$ and derive the inequality in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was told that we can prove the inequality starting with the LHS and obtain the RHS. Can we do that somehow, because it is supposed to be the easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $\dfrac{4\cdot5\cdot9}{|b|}$ and simplifying,
$$|45r-36| \le 4(|15r| + 16 )=|60r|+64.$$

The result immediately follows as

$$|45r-36|\le|45r|+36.$$